# php simple html dom <tr> bgcolor

Tags: php, dom, tr

ok i've been reading up on simple php html dom and so far it works great.

I have a table which i'm trying to convert to a mysql db.

I'm using this:

```
foreach($html->find('TR') as $row) {
  etc.etc.etc.
}
```

my table:

```
 <TR BGCOLOR="CCDDFF">
      <TD valign="top">
</TD>
</TR>
```

but how do i get the bgcolor from the tr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the `$row->getAttribute('bgcolor')` method?

Comment: seems $row->getAttribute('bgcolor') is working.

thanx. just reading it, made me think 'dÛh'